# Convert ringing frequency to phase margin for LDO stability

Tags: ringing, phase-margin

Based on ROHM document "Simple Test Method for Estimating the Stability of Linear Regulators", it showed that in page 2/4, the phase margin for Fig.5 Phase Margin = 0 deg, Fig.6 Phase Margin = 9.9 deg and so on.

[Simple Test Method for Estimating the Stability of Linear Regulator](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/applinote/ic/power/linear_regulator/linearreg_easy_stability_app-e.pdf)

1. My question is, how does they convert the ringing frequency to the phase margin? I know the relation between ringing to stability but i cant find the exact formula to convert this ringing to the phase margin.

Comment: Consider [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva381b/slva381b.pdf) and [this](http://eas.uccs.edu/~cwang/ECE5955_F2015/PowerElectronics_f2015/ch9/Sect9-4-2.pdf) document.

Comment: Ringing frequency has nothing to do with phase margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they're doing in the article is a step-response analysis. The load current is suddenly increased and on an oscilloscope the step response is examined.

What matters in that response is **not the frequency** but the amount of **ringing**. How many sine waves does it take for the response to become flat again?

Infinite sine waves means oscillation so an unstable system.

A few sine waves might indicate marginal stability (on the edge).

Less than one sine wave usually means that the system is quite stable.

Read more [in this article from TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva381b/slva381b.pdf) about the relation between stability and ringing.

Comment: Yes, but the question was: how did they come up with those values of phase margin.

Comment: @Chupacabras I guess it can be theoretically determined with lots of complex mathematics but more likely a (system) simulator is used to build a model of a typical feedback system, then through simulations we can make the table linking ringing to phase margin. To me it looks like that's what they do in the article I linked.

Comment: Ya I understand your meaning. But lets take an example for my case, the number of ringing is 2 time during initial power ON. See my waveform as below